# Encrypting MP3 files with GNUPG and PHP

Tags: php, gnupg

I am trying to use the built-in PHP functionality to encrypt a series of MP3 files. However, my attempts to do so have failed. The object-oriented version ($gpg = new gnupg();) throws Fatal error: Class 'gnupg' not found in [file].php and the procedural version ($resource = gnupg_init();) throws Fatal error: Call to undefined function gnupg_init() in [file].php.

We have a server running on CentOS 6.6, with PHP 5.3.3 installed, as well as the following files:

```
libgpg-error
gpgme
gnupg
libgpgme11
```

To the best of our knowledge, all the necessary files are installed correctly.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: use phpinfo(); to check gnupg is intall

Comment: You've rolled in the PECL extension I presume? http://pecl.php.net/package/gnupg

Comment: As an aside - you don't actually *need* to use the extension - if you've got GPG installed and running you can simply execute a command to it by opening a pipeline and passing the command in like `popen($sGPGCmd, 'w');`

Comment: The packages you mention are not php-related. Try to install the php extension of GPG